# C++ Google Protocol Buffers. RPC how to?

Tags: c++, rpc

I already followed 3 tutorials on google RPC tried 3 different sources. And always the same problem. I cannot get it to work.  I am very close now, I am using [protoserv](http://code.google.com/p/protoserv/).  The problem I am having now is in their tutorial it says:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
   EchoServiceImpl echo_service;
   RpcManager rpcman;
   ...
```

I cannot find how to access RpcManager and where its even located. I did a grep on the protobuf and protoserv dir to no avail. There is only RpcManager located inside .java packages.  Maybe its just a non-supoorted version, even tho it has the example in C++.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Even a link to a stable / simple C++ protobuf implementation would be great.

Comment: As far as I can tell they do not include the C++ version of `RpcManager` in their source. They note on their homepage that it is an Alpha version and subject to change. Perhaps the C++ version is a TODO?

Comment: bummer. Could you suggest a good source to use in my project?  I have tried protobuf-remote recently which i had no luck with.
server1 seems out of date as the last change was in 2010.
not sure on the others.

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be very late for this question, but it would be useful for understanding/implementing a Protobuf RPC system.

For how to build a HTTP server which handles the raw requests and responses please check [pbrpc](https://github.com/madwyn/pbrpc).

For how to process the requests and produce responses (building the RPC system) please check [libpbrpc](https://github.com/madwyn/libpbrpc).

Each project only contains several source files, they won't take long to read.